# right way of inserting data into two tables in database simultaneously using java

Tags: java, mysql

i'm trying two insert two table simultaneously with foreign keys but it is not inserting and i don't why it's not working. 
when i click the button, it only inserts the passenger table but leaves the luggage unfilled. I just want to get the id numbers of the foreign keys.
these are my code :-

The passenger database table:

[image]

The luggage database table:

[image]

and my code :-

```
private void InsertLuggageInfo() {
        try {
            String query_passenger = "INSERT INTO passenger (Firstname,Lastname,Email,"
                    + "PhoneNr,Address,Zipcode,City,Country_name) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query_passenger);

        stmt.setString(1, txtFirstname.getText());
        stmt.setString(2, txtLastname.getText());
        stmt.setString(3, txtEmail.getText());
        stmt.setString(4, txtPhoneNr.getText());
        stmt.setString(5, txtAddress.getText());
        stmt.setString(6, txtZipCode.getText());
        stmt.setString(7, txtCity.getText());
        stmt.setString(8, txtCountry.getText());

        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {
        String query_luggage = "INSERT INTO passenger (DateFound,TimeFound,"
                + "LuggageType_id,Brand_id,MainColor_id,Status_id,Size_id,"
                + "Weight_id,SecondColor_id,LuggageTag,Image,Location_Airport_id,"
                + "Airport_id,Passenger_id) "
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query_luggage);

        stmt.setString(1, txtDatum.getText());
        stmt.setString(2, txtTimeFound.getText());
        stmt.setInt(3, get_LuggageType_id());
        stmt.setInt(4, get_Brand_id());
        stmt.setInt(5, get_MainColor_id());
        stmt.setInt(6, get_Status_id());
        stmt.setInt(7, get_Size_id());
        stmt.setInt(8, get_Weight_id());
        stmt.setInt(9, get_SecondColor_id());
        stmt.setString(10, txtLuggageTag.getText());
        stmt.setString(11, imgLuggage.toString());
        stmt.setInt(12, get_LocationAirport_id());
        stmt.setInt(13, get_Airport_id());
        stmt.setInt(14, get_Passenger_id());



        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

my methods to get the id's :-

```
 public int get_LuggageType_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select LuggageType_id from luggagetype where LuggageType ='" + ddlLuggageType.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("LuggageType_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}

public int get_Brand_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select Brand_id from brand where Brand ='" + ddlMerk.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("Brand_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}

public int get_MainColor_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select MainColor_id from maincolor where Color ='" + ddlMainColor.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("MainColor_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}

public int get_Status_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select Status_id from status where Status ='" + ddlStatus.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("Status_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}

public int get_Size_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select Size_id from size where Size ='" + ddlMerk.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("Size_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}

public int get_Weight_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select Weight_id from weight where Weight ='" + ddlWeight.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("Weight");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}


public int get_Flight_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select Flight_id from flight where Flight_number ='" + ddlWeight.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("Flight_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}

public int get_SecondColor_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select SecondColor_id from secondcolor where Color ='" + ddlSecondColor.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("SecondColor_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}

public int get_LocationAirport_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select Location_Airport_id from location_airport where Location_name ='" + ddlLocationFound.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("Location_Airport_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}

public int get_Airport_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select Airport_id from airport where Airport_name ='" + ddlLuchthaven.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("Airport_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}



public int get_Passenger_id() {
    int id = 0;
    try {

        String query = "Select Passenger_id from passenger where Firstname ='" + txtFirstname.getText() + "'";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt("Passenger_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Verloren_bagageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: *"but leaves the luggage unfilled"* - Where do you try to insert data into `luggage`?

Comment: is it possible that 2nd query should read something like `INSERT INTO luggage...` instead of `INSERT INTO passenger...`?! I wonder there is no error in the logs...

Comment: Any exception?  What's the error?  `query_luggage` starts with "INSERT INTO _passenger_..." which should probably be INSERT INTO luggage..."

Comment: because of copy and paste i made that mistake, but i've changed it to luggage and still doesn't work this is the error  "SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 0)."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should change the way you get the generated ID. You can use stmt.getGeneratedKeys(), as following:

```
long passengerId = 0;
int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate();

if (affectedRows == 0) {
    throw new SQLException("Insert Passenger error: no rows were affected.");
}

try (ResultSet generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
        passengerID = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
    }
    else {
        throw new SQLException("Insert Passenger error: no ID obtained.");
    }
}
```

This will garantee you get the new inserted data ID (your passenger FK).

Also, try to use `stmt.executeUpdate()` for both Inserts.

Comment: i still get this error "java.sql.SQLException: Generated keys not requested. You need to specify Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate(), Statement.executeLargeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement()."